# What material is permeable for plant roots, but "impermeable" for fungi & bacteria?

Tags: microbiology, plant-physiology, biotechnology, experimental-design

I'm designing an experiment where the roots of the plant will grow in a sterile environment while the shoot will grow in a non-sterile grow room. For this reason the environments of the shoot and the root should have some form of physical separation.

Is there any material that allows roots to grow through it but will stop fungi and bacteria?

Comment: root and shoot grow in different directions. Why can't you sterilize your media and cover it with an impermeable material?

Answer (score 1):

I might have found a solution! Kuijken et al. (2015) first germinate seeds in a sterile eppendorf filled with agar and nutrients. They then cut off the bottom of the eppendorf and stick it through the lid of a sterile plastic jar and pad it with sterile cotton. So I guess they are using the agar as a material that is permeable to the roots and "impermeable" to bacteria and fungi.

Kuijken, R. C., Snel, J. F., Heddes, M. M., Bouwmeester, H. J., & Marcelis, L. F. (2015). The importance of a sterile rhizosphere when phenotyping for root exudation. Plant and Soil, 387(1-2), 131-142.